# Why i can't create a Kotlin object from java side?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm investigating Kotlin interop with java.

I can't find an answer for such thing. I have an object from kotlin:

```
object Test {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    }
}
```

In decompiled form it looks like this:

```
public final class Test {
   public static final Test INSTANCE;

   public final void main(@NotNull String[] args) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(args, "args");
   }

   static {
      Test var0 = new Test();
      INSTANCE = var0;
   }
}
```

The question is: why when i try to create an object, i see error that Test has private access? There's no private constructors in decompiled code...

Comment: I'm seeing the private constructor with `javap -p Test`. I guess your decompiler isn't including private members?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create instances of `object`s. That's how Kotlin defines singletons. If you want to be able to instantiate it, you must declare it as a normal `class`.

If you do in fact want it to be a singleton, but want that single instance on the Java side, I suppose you could reference it as `Test.INSTANCE`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just wondering what prevents from creation? I can't see anything in the decompiled code..

Comment: I'm not entirely certain of the technical reasons. Perhaps there is a limitation on the decompiler but the constructor really IS private. What I do know is that, if you could create instances from the Java side, that would be breaking the singleton contract with unpleasant consequences.

Comment: @the_kaba Would you consider accepting this answer?